# How to route MediaPlayer1 to wired headset and MediaPlayer2 to BT headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to play two files at the same time and route one to wired headset and the other to the BT headset.  Is this even possible? Any ideas how I can achieve this? I'm targeting OS 2.3 and greater.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating two `MediaPlayer`s with different stream types:

```
btPlayer = new MediaPlayer(...);
wiredPlayer = new MediaPlayer(...);
...
btPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
wiredPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
...
```

Of cause you'll need to put extra code to redirect `btPlayer` to bluetooth headset. For this you'll need to use `startBluetoothSco()` and `setBluetoothScoOn()`.

Also note, that audio can be redirected to bluetooth headset only on `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL`. But if you are using a2dp bluetooth device, you can redirect audio to this device in `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` stream as well.